# .net Core FileStreamResult in img src does not work on mobile device

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a .net core web api that is returning a FileStreamResult like:

```
public ActionResult DrawSummaryImage(int id, int pageNumber = 1)
{
    var ms = GetImageAsMemoryStream(id, pageNumber);

    return File(ms, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
}
```

In my .cshtml page I have:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawSummaryImage", "Tournament", new { id = Id, pageNumber = 1 })" alt="Draw Summary" />
```

This works fine when viewed on a laptop/desktop, however when viewing the same page on a mobile device (iPhone, Android, iPad), the page renders with the alt text.

Any ideas why this might be happening and what I can do to make work on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was nothing to do with mobile…the issue was that on the mobile device I was not logged in. The page allowed anonymous but the FileStreamResult call did not. By setting allow anonymous on that call everything worked as expected.